# Date computation for queries in Grafana

Tags: grafana, prometheus

*(See updated, clearer explanation below: go to "Update on 2019-09-20")*

<s>I am looking for a way for Grafana to query my Prometheus data source with variable labels which are *YYYY-MM-DD* dates, and moreover, a date relative to current day.</s>

I want to see the last 4 days, I could create a Grafana graph with 4 queries with correct labels as follows, and it would work, but I would need to update my graph everyday:

- `myapp_metric_foo{task_date="2019-09-16"}`
- `myapp_metric_foo{task_date="2019-09-17"}`
- `myapp_metric_foo{task_date="2019-09-18"}`
- `myapp_metric_foo{task_date="2019-09-19"}`

To avoid that, I am looking for some date computation formula like: `now - 1 day | format_date "YYYY-MM-DD"`

So my Grafana graph queries example would be:

- `myapp_metric_foo{task_date="{{ now | format_date "YYYY-MM-DD" }}"}`
- `myapp_metric_foo{task_date="{{ now - 1 day | format_date "YYYY-MM-DD" }}"}`
- `myapp_metric_foo{task_date="{{ now - 2 day | format_date "YYYY-MM-DD" }}"}`
- `myapp_metric_foo{task_date="{{ now - 3 day | format_date "YYYY-MM-DD" }}"}`

I couldn't find anything in Grafana that seems to allow such thing.

Another idea would be to update existing graph from a external script via Grafana API...

---

*Update on 2019-09-20:*

It looks like I need to give more explanation about the application.

### **Application context**

The instrumented application *myapp* runs tasks/jobs (let's say it's calculation jobs that can take some time).
Each task has a `task_date` (id. when it was submitted. **Set at task creation: it will never change**) and can be in one of the 3 following state/status:

- `new`
- `running`
- `done`

When *Prometheus* scrapes *myapp*, *myapp* tells *Prometheus* how many tasks:

- are in state `new`, grouped by `task_date`
- are in state `running`, grouped by `task_date`
- are in state `done`, grouped by `task_date`

The application deletes `done` tasks older than 7 days.

### **Application data**

Let's say the application has, at 2019-09-19 14h00, the following tasks in it's database:

```
+----+------------+---------+---+
| ID | task_date  | status  | … |
+----+------------+---------+---+
| 42 | 2019-09-12 | done    | … |
| 43 | 2019-09-12 | done    | … |
| 44 | 2019-09-12 | done    | … |
| 45 | 2019-09-13 | done    | … |
| 46 | 2019-09-15 | done    | … |
| 47 | 2019-09-15 | done    | … |
| 48 | 2019-09-16 | done    | … |
| 49 | 2019-09-17 | running | … |
| 50 | 2019-09-17 | done    | … |
| 51 | 2019-09-17 | done    | … |
| 52 | 2019-09-18 | new     | … |
| 53 | 2019-09-18 | running | … |
| 54 | 2019-09-18 | running | … |
| 55 | 2019-09-18 | done    | … |
| 56 | 2019-09-18 | done    | … |
| 57 | 2019-09-19 | new     | … |
| 58 | 2019-09-19 | new     | … |
| 59 | 2019-09-19 | running | … |
+----+------------+---------+---+
```

The metrics exposed to *Prometheus* by *myapp*, at 2019-09-19 18h00 would be (text-based format):

```
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-12",status="done"} 3
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-13",status="done"} 1
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-15",status="done"} 2
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-16",status="done"} 1
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-17",status="running"} 1
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-17",status="done"} 2
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-18",status="new"} 1
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-18",status="running"} 2
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-18",status="done"} 2
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-19",status="new"} 2
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-19",status="running"} 1
```

Let's suppose the following occurs on the application afterwards:

- A task submitted at day 2019-09-18 starts (moves from `new` to `running`)
- A task submitted at day 2019-09-19 finishes (moves from `running` to `done`)
- Tasks having a `task_date` older than 7 days are deleted (here tasks for 2019-09-12)
- A new task is submitted at 2019-09-20 00h43m

A few hours later, at 2019-09-20 02h00, the new exposed metrics ouput would be:

```
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-12",status="done"} 3
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-13",status="done"} 1
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-15",status="done"} 2
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-16",status="done"} 1
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-17",status="running"} 1
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-17",status="done"} 2
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-18",status="running"} 3
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-18",status="done"} 2
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-19",status="new"} 2
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-19",status="done"} 1
myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-20",status="done"} 1
```

My *Grafana* graph (visualization type=Graph) would use the following 4 *PromQL* queries (**4**, because I only want to see the last **4** days):

- Query A

  - Metrics: `myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-17"}`
  - Legend: `{{status}} tasks submitted 3 days ago`
- Query B

  - Metrics: `myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-18"}`
  - Legend: `{{status}} tasks submitted 2 days ago`
- Query C

  - Metrics: `myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-19"}`
  - Legend: `{{status}} tasks submitted yesterday`
- Query D

  - Metrics: `myapp_tasks_total{task_date="2019-09-20"}`
  - Legend: `{{status}} tasks submitted today`

This would produces 4*3=12 curves max (depending on how many distinct statuses exists for each days) that would help me keep tracks of application load (number of tasks) and speed (*time-to-done*).

### **The question**

The *Prometheus* instrumenting part is not a problem for me: I know how to get my data from my database and how to expose it to *Prometheus*.

My issue is for the *PromQL* queries Grafana needs: The 4 queries I gave above will only be pertinent when accessing Grafana the 2019-09-20: I need a way to dynamically "change" the `task_date=` criteria in each query.

I was hoping *Grafana* had a custom DSL that would allow me to tell it:

> Hey, take your `$__to` variable, removes *x* days and format it to "YYYY-MM-DD".

Something like: `{{ $__to - x * 86400000 | format_date "YYYY-MM-DD" }}`

(1 day = 86400000 ms)

Another idea would be to manually create the graph and periodically update it from a external script via Grafana API...

Comment: Based on your update, there are not enough information for making what you want. There is a similar usage in k8s with cron triggering task with labels that are specific to the start time of the task. Based on that experience, I would say you are missing a gauge metric giving you the start time (in epoch) of the task.

Comment: @CDuv did you figure this out?

Comment: No, I did not :-(

Answer (score 0):

Since they have different label values (`task_date``) they are considered different metrics. You have to remove the dimension (the label).

**Remove the label at request time**

[Replace the label](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace) with an empty value. This supposes it doesn't create a duplicated metric.

```
label_replace(up{job="myapp_metric_foo, "task_date", "", "task_date", ".*")
```

Or [aggregate the metrics](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#aggregation-operators):

```
max(myapp_metric_foo) WITHOUT(task_date)
```

**Remove the label at ingestion time**

In your Prometheus, configuration, you can use [metric relabeling](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs) to drop the label

```
metric_relabel_configs:
- regex: 'container_label_com_amazonaws_ecs_task_arn'
  action: labeldrop
```

In my opinion, you'd better drop it at ingest time. Having a label different per day doesn't really make sense ; unless it is some kind of very long scheduled job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When re-reading my question the next day it became clear I wasn't clear enough (hence your *off-topic* answer): Please take a look at my update that better explains the context and my need.